# download html page for offline use

Tags: html, download, wget, offline

I want to make an html page available for offline viewing by downloading the html and all images / css resources from it, but not other pages which are links.

I was looking at [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) and [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) but could not find the right set of arguments (I need the command line).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried wget -p? You probably also want -k (convert links) so that href tags in your downloaded HTML files will still work.

Comment: thanks - it does not download images though. I see some posts about version 1.12 have better support for my scenario. Is this true, and if so how can I get it for windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to download using the newest version of `wget`, get it using cygwin installer
and use this version

```
wget -m –w 2 –p -E -k –P {target-dir} http://{website}
```

to mirror {website} to {target-dir} (without images in 1.11.4).

Leave out `-w 2` to speed up the progress.

Comment: I get "unrecognized option `--HTML-extension'". I use wget 1.11.4 for windows. when I remove the HTML-extension flag it runs but outputs strange messages "Resolving \226w... failed: Unknown host." What do they mean? it did save the site but w/o html data.

Comment: Try the new command line. It would help if you paste the error message somewhere.

Comment: Install the cygwin version of wget. they have the newest version. If this doesnt work, there is a compile of the newest wget version in a sourceforge forum of wingnu.

Comment: I am checking cygwin but this will probably not be a valid option for me due to the large installation time (I may need to do it on more machines). Did the command you suggested me worked on your windows version (if you have one) and download the images?

Comment: Maybe you can check the dll dependencies of wget.exe in the cygwin package and just copy them together with wget.exe. You do not even need a cygwin installation when they are all together in one folder. You could even statically link them together.

Comment: Thanks. cygwin download is slow... just to save me a goose chase: did you saw that with the cygwin version wget does download images, and that with the windows version it does not?

Comment: @YaronNaveh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1539/discussion-between-marc-and-yaron-naveh)

Answer (score -1):

For one page, the following wget command line parameters should be enough. Please keep in mind that it might not download everything including background images attached to CSS files etc.

```
wget -p <webpage>
```

Also try `wget --help` for a list of all command line parameters.

Comment: this does not download images. I'm not sure which parameters I should use

Comment: -p is meant to download images. Maybe your images are embedded in the stylesheet as background images?

From the help page:   -p,  --page-requisites    get all images, etc. needed to display HTML page.